# Objective-C: how to pass parameter to method

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
int land4Random = arc4random_uniform(3);
if (land4Random == 0)
{
    Land4.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"GoodLandBR.jpg"];
}
if (land4Random == 1)
{
    Land4.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"DeadLand.jpg"];
}
```

I would like to use this block of code many times, but i do not know how to make method of it.

Comment: The fact that you get it as an outlet is completely irrelevant. A UIImageView is a UIImageView; where you got it from doesn't affect the syntax of parameter passing in any way.

Comment: Just a note. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @Fogmeister *SHOULD start with a lowercase letter. While it will still function properly with an uppercase, it's just bad form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read some programming introduction and general concepts book, as this question is really really basic, but here you go:

```
- (void)setRandomImageToImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    int land4Random = arc4random_uniform(2);
    if (land4Random == 0)
    {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"GoodLandBR.jpg"];
    }
    else if (land4Random == 1)
    {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"DeadLand.jpg"];
    }
}
```

Note that you had 3 as the upper bound on the random value, but you only have two valid values. Either use `arc4random_uniform(2)` or provide code for the third case when `land4Random == 2`.

Then you just call it like:

```
[self setRandomImageToImageView:land4];
```

etc.

---

Also try to follow coding conventions and don't start your variable names with upper case.